# How can I write use previous returned value of an observable with redux-observable?

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I don't know my question title is suitable for this question.
I would like to use returned value of someAsync1 (same as v2) as argument of action1 inside of flatMap.

```
const anEpic = ($action: ActionsObservable<MyAction>, store: Store<MyRootStore>) => {
return $action.ofType(ActionTypes.AN_ASYNC_ACTION)
    .switchMap((v1) => someAsync1(v1)) 
    .switchMap((v2) => someAsync2(v2))
    .map((v) => applyToUI(v))
    .flatMap((v) => Observable.concat(Observable.of(action1(v)), Observable.of(action2(true)))) // 
}
```

I guess I can use that value by injecting v2 to returned value of someAsync2. But that code looks disgusting. 
What is clever way to do this with redux-observable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switchMap` technically means, well, ***switch*** to another Observable stream. That means there is no way for you to retain the value because your observer is now observing a different source.

There are a few ways to do the so called "retaining" the values from one stream to another, depending on which one you prefer.

#### 1. Behaviour Subject

This is the most preferred way, because the purpose of `BehaviourSubject` *is* to retain a value of an `Observable`:

```js
//initialize a BehaviourSubject
let v2BSubject = new BehaviourSubject<any>(null);

const anEpic = ($action: ActionsObservable<MyAction>, store: Store<MyRootStore>) => {
    return $action.ofType(ActionTypes.AN_ASYNC_ACTION)
        .switchMap((v1) => someAsync1(v1))
        .switchMap((v2) => {
            //store your v2 value here!
            v2BSubject.next(v2);
            return someAsync2(v2)
        })
        .map((v) => applyToUI(v))
        .flatMap((v) => {
            //get your v2 values here
            let v2Value = v2BSubject.value;
            return Observable.concat(Observable.of(action1(v)), Observable.of(action2(true)))
        }) //
}
```

or you can use it as an `Observable`. That way you can treat it as an observable and use whatever rxjs operator can provide:

```
.flatMap((v) => {
    return Observable.concat(Observable.of(action1(v)), v2BSubject.asObservable())
})
```

#### 2. Use `.map` to propagate the value.

This is rather hacky, but gets the job done. However do note it's modifying the stream source. If you have many operations along the pipe, it may blow up quickly and hard to manage:

```js
 const anEpic = ($action: ActionsObservable<MyAction>, store: Store<MyRootStore>) => {
    return $action.ofType(ActionTypes.AN_ASYNC_ACTION)
        .switchMap((v1) => someAsync1(v1))
        .switchMap((v2) => {
            someAsync2(v2)
                .map(afterSomeAsync2 => {
                    return {
                        v1Value: v2,
                        v2Value: afterSomeAsync2
                    }
                })
        })
        .map(({v1Value, v2Value}) => {
            return applyToUI(v1Value).map(v1 => {
                return {
                    v1Value: v1,
                    v2Value: v2Value
                }
            })
        })
        .flatMap(({v1Value, v2Value}) => {
            return Observable.concat(Observable.of(action1(v1Value)), Observable.of(v2Value))
        })
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your answer cleared my misunderstanding of rxjs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to apply your operators directly on the returned inner Observables instead of on the collapsed outer chain. You can then access the values emitted because they're part of the closures.

That's probably confusing, but hopefully this code makes it clear:

```
const anEpic = ($action: ActionsObservable<MyAction>, store: Store<MyRootStore>) => {
  return $action.ofType(ActionTypes.AN_ASYNC_ACTION)
    .switchMap((v1) =>
      someAsync1(v1)
        .switchMap((v2) =>
          someAsync2(v2)
            .map((v) => applyToUI(v))
            .flatMap((v) => Observable.of(action1(v, v1, v2), action2(true))
        )
    ) 
  }
```

This pattern is also what you would have to use if you wanted to catch any errors by `someAsync1` or `someAsync2` because if you let the error propagate to the top-level chain the epic will have stopped listening for future actions.

e.g. if your epic looks like this:

```
const somethingEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.ofType(SOMETHING)
    .switchMap(action => someAsync1(v1))
    .map(() => ({ type: SOMETHING_FULFILLED }))
    .catch(error => Observable.of({
      type: SOMETHING_REJECTED,
      error
    }));
  }
```

When the error reaches the `catch` operator it's too late, your epic is no longer listening for future actions. You could "restart" it, but this can have unexpected consequences so its best to avoid this pattern.

Instead, catch the error before it propagates out

```
const somethingEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.ofType(SOMETHING)
    .switchMap(action =>
      someAsync1(v1)
        .map(() => ({ type: SOMETHING_FULFILLED }))
        .catch(error => Observable.of({
          type: SOMETHING_REJECTED,
          error
        }))
    );
  }
```

Some people refer to this as "isolating your observer chains".

---

Also notice how I didn't need to use `concat` with multiple `of` because `of` supports any number of arguments.